# ESLint throwing "Parsing error: Unexpected token :" on variable that ends in :

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am working on the jest project and the linter is throwing me an issue...

> error  Parsing error: Unexpected token :

I have been playing with the lint configuration a bit and I am not sure what I messed up but when I go to the code I see...

```
const BULLET: string = chalk.bold('\u25cf');
```

This seems weird to me (a name ending in :) is this a common React practice or just a typo? Is there a way to tell ESLint to ignore this convention throughout?

Comment: It is invalid JS. You sure you're not using TypeScript?

Comment: I want to agree with you but here is the FB code...

https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-validate/src/utils.js (ln 14)

Why is it on their master branch?

Comment: Like are you sure it isn't a babel or React thing?

Comment: See the link but I don't see TS as a dependency

Comment: Because the project uses TypeScript? And *is* in the Jest `devDependencies`, because there's TypeScript code in it.

Comment: interesting I missed it the first time but it is still odd the extension isn't TS

Comment: This is not TS. It's flow syntax. You need eslint plugin for flow and mark the file with //@flow comment.

Comment: Ahhh I have removed all those temporarily I will try adding them back!

Answer (score 2):

This is  flow syntax. You need to mark your file with

```
//@flow
```

And probably also add Babel and ESlint plugin for flow syntax.

See https://flow.org/en/

Comment: Lets take this https://github.com/jrgleason/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-validate/src/__tests__/fixtures/jest_config.js as an example. I have added plugin: [ 'flowtype' ] but when I run I still get the error on the string:. I am not using the babel-parser is that a problem for flow? I want to avoid it

Comment: @jackie Its no valid javascript, you need some kind of preprocessor, at least to remove the annotations.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without Babel?

Comment: @Jackie Of course, for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-node But if you don't want to use flow, why don't you just remove the annotations? To just make ESLint understand it, there is the plugin https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype

Comment: Thanks yeah I don't want to remove it because it isn't my project.

Comment: So the flow-node looks like it just removes the annotations. Does that mean I would have to run eslint once with just the flow rules, then remove annotations, then run eslint again? Maybe you are right about removing it, what would be the replacement?

Comment: @Jackie For ESLint just use that eslint plugin I have linked above.

Comment: eslint plugin uses Babel. Seems so redundant

Comment: And I would still need to run eslint 2x once before removing annotations and once after

Comment: @Jackie You are right, I am gonna remove my comments about that. They use babel themselves to translate their code, nothing more. The same is valid for the eslint flow plugin though.

Comment: RT I was thinking about that I can easily run flow (I tried `./node_modules/.bin/flow check`). But I don't know how to then remove the annotations without changing the file. Maybe I need to configure to use Webpack so that it is just a stream.

Comment: yeah but going to Webpack is a big step, guess I'll have to bite the bullet thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm wrong; this is indeed Flow syntax. See the other response for the correct answer.

<strike>That's Typescript syntax. You should configure your linter to support typescript.</strike>

For ESLint:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript-eslint-parser
```

And in your ESLint configuration file:

```
"parser": "typescript-eslint-parser"
```

Comment: Interesting that it has a .js extension. Must be a babel thing?

Comment: Flow, not typescript.